# pgfgantt xcolor Error undefined color

Tags: color, pgfgantt

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}




\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
time slot unit=month,
title/.append style={draw=none, fill=RoyalBlue!50!black},
title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=OliveGreen!75},
bar height=.6,
bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3,
group peaks height=.2,
bar incomplete/.append style={fill=Maroon}
]{2010-09}{2011-12}
\gantttitlecalendar{year} \\
\ganttbar[
progress=100,
bar progress label font=\small\color{OliveGreen!75},
bar progress label node/.append style={right=4pt},
bar label font=\normalsize\color{OliveGreen},
name=pp
]{Preliminary Project}{2010-09}{2010-12} \\
\ganttset{progress label text={}, link/.style={black, -to}}
\ganttgroup{Objective 1}{2011-01}{2011-12} \\
\ganttbar[progress=4, name=T1A]{Task A}{2011-01}{2011-06} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Task B}{2011-07}{2011-12} \\
\ganttgroup{Objective 2}{2011-01}{2011-12} \\
\ganttbar[progress=15, name=T2A]{Task A}{2011-01}{2011-09} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Task B}{2011-10}{2011-12} \\
\ganttgroup{Objective 3}{2011-05}{2011-08} \\
\ganttbar[progress=0]{Task A}{2011-05}{2011-08}
\ganttset{link/.style={OliveGreen}}
\ganttlink[link mid=.4]{pp}{T1A}
\ganttlink[link mid=.159]{pp}{T2A}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

I have this example from the pgfgantt documentation. But it doesn't work.
I get this error:

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `OliveGreen'.See the xcolor
> package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate
> help.... ...ess=4, name=T1A]{Task A}{2011-01}{2011-06}

Answer (score 2):

`OliveGreen` is a color name which stems from dvips. If you want to be able to refer to that color directly, you have to load `xcolor` with the option `[dvipsnames]` which can be achieved by adding the line `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` just before loading `pgfgantt`.

As you can see e.g. in this [LaTeX WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) this also applies for the other colors used in your example that are not available, like `RoyalBlue` and `Maroon`.

Comment: thanks, i tried this before. Maybe i had a typo. But now it works.

Comment: @Thomas you are welcome. Additionally to thanking me, you can accept this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, thank you.